# Alternatives to ESRI Business Analyst

Tags: business, geomarketing, business-analyst

Does there exist any other software than business analyst that can do store-level trade area analysis without much programming overhead? I am particularly interested in:

1. Creating customer-derived trade areas that represent x% of sales
2. Location analysis using a Huff-style model with competition and site attributes (like size)

The data that comes with the software is not really an added benefit for me since I already have access to similar products.

Comment: This [similar question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6219/open-source-gis-implementation-of-the-huff-model) may give you some other ideas about the Huff model portion of your question.

Comment: @RyanDalton I remember seeing this question before, but I don't think a solution was reached. I will give it another read in case I missed something the first time around. Thanks!

Comment: Correct, no real "solution" was reached, but I thought the discussion points might point you in a helpful direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for commercial product then [RegioGraph](http://www.gfk-regiograph.com/en/applications.html) is an alternate. If you need more info about it just let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. I will check it out. If you have used both, how do the two products compare?

Answer (score 3):

I would strongly recommend Maptitude as a geospatial software package to meet your spatial analysis needs.  I have been a user of the software for about 3 years now, as the software is quite affordable compares to MapInfo and ESRI Business Analyst Online.  The software is aimed at the business person who needs to do site selection work, demographic analysis, and advanced trade area analysis.  The software is easy to use, customizable, and can easily bring in point data from an Excel Spreadsheet with your store attribute data including latitude/longitude or by address (the software comes with a great geocoder).  You can also build your own formulas to do a Huff Model analysis.  Included with your country package of choice is detailed census data available at the county, zip code and tract levels.

Maptitude - http://www.caliper.com/maptovu.htm
Huff Model Example - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9d0Ccsj2Ct4