# Gravity/Huff model tools in QGIS without rasterlang plugin?

Tags: qgis, gravity-model

As the person of this question:

[Gravity/Huff model tools](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49402/gravity-huff-model-tools)

I am looking for a tool to simulate a gravity model using a point-based layer.

As in the case there, my points have a z-value and the higher this value, the larger is their "sphere of influence". Their influence is inversely proportional to the distance to the center.

The answer given there by jake would be perfect, but unfortunately it requires the rasterlang plugin which, as far as I understand, is not supported anymore (or at least it does not work on my QGIS 2.8.2)

So.. does anyone have any other idea?