# When to use spatial regression for the proximity analysis

Tags: qgis, distance, proximity, regression

I am not sure about whether I should use spatial regression for the proximity analysis I am trying to do.

I’ll just describe the scenario and goal:

People claim that convenience stores lower nearby home property values. I want to actually prove this. So I want to essentially prove: is there a statistically significant relationship between the value of your house and how close you are to a convenience store?

Here are the data layers I am working with for the city of focus:

- vector polygons of houses in 2010 (contains property values of each house)
- vector polygons of houses in 2015 (contains property values of each house)
- vector polygons of convenience stores in 2015

Basically I am thinking I would need to first find out how much property values have changed between 2010 and 2015, by taking the 2015 houses layer and subtracting the 2010 houses layer. From this, I would produce a layer that would show the houses in either red (negative) or green (positive) with different shades. So in this new layer, if a house were red, it would mean the house went down in value and if it were green, it would mean the house went up in value. I would imagine these being in different shades, so pink would mean just went down a little bit in value, and dark red would mean went way down in value, and similarly for green, where light green means went up a little bit in value and dark green means went way up in value. Of course, I would first need to see if there is spatial autocorrelation associated with property values.

I would now have all of these red and green houses of various shades and convenience stores. My question is, how do I show if there is a relationship between proximity to convenience stores and the property values of the houses? Normally I would think this would just require regression, but since this is dealing with proximity, wouldn’t this require spatial regression or a geographically weighted regression? Does my approach sound reasonable? I am just trying to figure out what the output of this regression would look like and how to interpret it. Which tools and methods in QGIS would I need for this?

Comment: You may want to look at something like a cross-K statistic. I have a LUP paper that used an inhomogenious cross-k to address the question of development being attracted to open spaces and it is a fairly clear inference. You can use a Monte Carlo to evaluate significance.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like an interesting piece of work.
A simple statistical solution may be to map linear regression residuals of each house, based on distance vs property value change. (There are a million other factors here, like accessibility, linear distance isn't necessarily reflective of proximity etc)

So a simple starting activity could be:

- Introduce a new calculated field on your house vector polygons which is a calculated field based on distance to nearest convenience store
- Introduce a new field called "Residuals". This will be the value of the residual against linear regression.

Then you can map the residuals.

Additional maps to supplement this could be

- You could colour as per your above red/green but from the following perspectives
- Houses that are within 500m
- Houses greater than 500m
  (or whatever distance you feel is appropriate).

Alternatively - You could also make the map 'Convenience Store Centric' - that is, map the convenience store's that have X number of houses with 500m that are below average. (maybe resize the 'dot' location of the convenience store.

Something else you may want to consider, is - whether or not a house is within a selected distance of TWO convenience stores. (this could introduce some kind of weighted analysis element to your mapping).

There is a similar question asked here, which gives more detail about the tools that they used.

[Calculating spatial correlation between features from two separate layers in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/172759/calculating-spatial-correlation-between-features-from-two-separate-layers-in-qgi)

Calculating the residual is probably the hard part, it might be simple enough to make a non-spatial table, with the residual results, and just do a join back to your geographic data. (That way you could perform the residual linear regression outside of QGIS and then import it back in as a flat table).

Comment: Thank you for the great suggestions! You make a good point by considering when a house is within distance of two convenience stores, since I don't think simply being near one convenience store would tell us all we need to know. A house being 50 feet away from a convenience store may be impacted less than a house 100 feet away from 10 convenience stores. For this reason, do you think it would be a good idea to create a kernel density around the convenience stores to show both convenience store proximity and density, rather than just considering proximity to only the nearest convenience store?

Comment: I would run simple analysis to begin with, because this can give high level insight. It may be that - as you start to introduce more variables, the instance of these occurrences are minimal are may not be worthwhile investigating. Again, analysis will help here. Start with a simple question of 'how many houses are within X distance of more than 1 convenience store' and go from there.